# How to make a service that running in the background even if the app's already destroyed?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mobile

I want to make a feature to notify user when there's data changes in my firebase database. The problem is when the app is destroyed, then the service automatically destroyed. After that when the data in database change, my app won't notify the user.

Here's some snippet code for my apps.

Service :

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d(TAG, "DogNotificationService created")

        val phone = intent?.extras?.getString("PHONE")

        if(isFirstTime) {
            val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

            notificationReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("walker/$phone/notification")

            val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO)

            coroutineScope.launch {
                launchListener()
            }

            isFirstTime = false
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    fun launchListener() {
        valueEventListener =
            notificationReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Read failed: " + p0.message)
                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    val notificationData = p0.getValue(String::class.java)

                    if(count > 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, notificationData)
                        sendNotification(notificationData!!)
                    }

                    count++
                }

            })
    }
```

When I start the service :

```
private fun startNotificationService() {
        val intent = Intent(context, DogNotificationService::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("PHONE", "081293312313")

        Log.d(TAG, "Start notification service")

        activity?.startService(intent)
    }
```

If any idea to do this approach, please help.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is push notifications. Holding a constantly running service isn't the way to do this. You don't see Messages or Gmail constantly running a service.

Comment: Yeah I think so. In your opinion, what approach should I take to solve this case,  Should I use FCM for this? Or there's any android library for this? The push notification should be from device to device, and it is fire when there's data changes in the firebase database.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with notifications in about seven years. Don't have any recommendations.

Comment: It's ok, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I was working in an app to keep track of the users to allow them record their tracks and found out that services can be killed at any moment if the android system requires free memory. Even if your service has [wakelocks](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) or is running in foreground.

The solution I found was to use [alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) with a foreground service, if you schedule alarms this alarms will be fired whether your app is still executing or not. That way my app could get the device position even though the system had killed the app due to lack of resources. It's the only solution I found that works in this scenario. An alarm that wakes up the service.

The idea came to me in some google i/o when they said that if you really need your app to continue no matter what you should use alarms instead of services.

Besides that, if you need the app to be awaked constantly then use `exact` alarms as the `inexact` ones in some devices they might be fired 5 minutes later if the time that they should be fired is too near to the current time.

Comment: The problem is I want to show the notification when there's data changes in my firebase database. I don't know when the exact time for my alarm to fire neither can I get the message from the firebase (The message I want to show in the database).

Comment: Well, it's not perfect but if your service is a `foreground service` it shouldn't be killed just by leaving the app, so it should continue running for a time. The alarms are set to wake up the service in case the app gets killed by the system so you at least know that the service will not be stopped indefinitely. I know it's not perfect as you can't be 100% sure you'll get the notification in real time (only if the foreground service is not killed) but it's the best solution I have, and I wanted to share it in case it can help you.

Comment: Thanks sir, really appreciated.